# An error was thrown in afterAll TypeError: Cannot read property 'ids' of undefined

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am new to angular and i tried to write simple unit test for my component. My test fail time to time ant i get the following error: An error was thrown in afterAll TypeError: Cannot read property 'ids' of undefined and i also attached the error trace[image]

This is my component implementation:

```js
    ngOnInit() {
        this.groupValueForm.valueChanges.subscribe((group: BasicGroup) => {
          this.store.dispatch(GroupActions.selectGroup({ group: group }));
        });
        this.store.dispatch(GroupActions.getAllGroups());
        this.store.pipe(select(selectAllGroups)).subscribe((basicGroups: BasicGroup[]) => {
          this.groups = basicGroups;
        });
      }
```

this is my test class implementation:

```js
      beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          imports: [
            TopPanelModule,
            STORE_MODULE_TEST
          ],
          providers: [
            { provide: COUNTRY_ID, useValue: 'sv-SE' },
            { provide: TranslateService, useValue: mockTranslateService },
            provideMockStore({ initialState })
          ]
        });
        store = TestBed.inject(MockStore);
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TopPanelComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
      });
    
      it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
      });
    
      it('should use the groupList from store', (done: DoneFn)  => {
        spyOn(store, 'pipe').and.returnValue(of(groups));
        component.ngOnInit();
        store.pipe().subscribe(resp=>{
          expect(component.groups).toEqual(groups);
          done();
        })
      });
    
      it('should dispatch getAllGroups', () => {
        spyOn(component['store'], 'dispatch');
        component.ngOnInit();
        expect(component['store'].dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(GroupActions.getAllGroups());
      });
    
      afterEach(() => {
        fixture.destroy();
      });
```

Comment: do you have `ngOnDestroy` method in the `TopPanelComponent`? May you please show it as well?

Comment: @IAfanasov this is : ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.destroy.next();
    this.destroy.complete();
  }

Comment: doesn't not seem like an error source. I can only guess `this. destroy`  used somewhere else. the code of whole component might help. also you might try to explore the files from the error stack trace. there might be clues.

Comment: @AmilaEranda can you show `STORE_MODULE_TEST`?

Comment: @Buczkowski this is: export const STORE_MODULE_TEST = StoreModule.forRoot({
  ...fromRoot.reducers,
  'core': combineReducers(fromCore.coreReducers)
}, {
  runtimeChecks: {
    strictStateImmutability: true,
    strictActionImmutability: true,
    strictStateSerializability: false,
    strictActionSerializability: false
  }
});

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one of potential fixes as your error suggest that `yourEntityFeatureSliceName` (in case below) is `undefined`. In other hand if you don't want to override initial state you can always override selectors and as I wrote in comments it could be `selectAll` or `selectEntities` - `selectAllGroups`.

```
import {MockStore, provideMockStore} from '@ngrx/store/testing';

let store$: MockStore;

beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    // Put other dependencies
    providers: [
      provideMockStore({
        initialState: {
          yourEntityFeatureSliceName: { // Update name
            ids: [],
            entities: {}
          }
        }
      })
    ]
  });

  store$ = TestBed.inject(MockStore);
});
```

to override selector:

```
store.overrideSelector(selectAllGroups, {}); // Provide data
```

Beside all of that - note that you spy on `store.pipe` in test case and first `fixture.detectChanges();` call is in `beforeEach` so `ngOnInit` will be executed before spy.